# Azure notification hub device registration issue

Tags: cordova, azure, notifications, azure-notificationhub

I have a notification hub configured and everything seems to be working correctly from a user point of view in my cordova app. Per my testing on production, new devices get registered in the notification hub and I will be able to receive push notification on these devices.

However, I get at least 200+ push notification registration on a daily basis according to the notification hub dashboard. I have manually counted the number of registration operation for the period of Aug/4 - Aug/31 and at least 11,000 registration operation has been performed. This 11,000++ registration operation which contradict with the other statistic data on the image below  "REGISTRATION IN THIS NOTIFICATION HUB: 5940"

[image]

Here is also a screenshot of the 'Monitor' tab and notice that there are no major errors shown in the table:

[image]

My question is: Where are the other hundreds of registrations that I get on a daily basis? Why are they not shown as registered devices? Counting for 1 month only, I should see 11,000++ devices registered while there is only 5940 devices?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit confusing, but there's a difference between *registrations* and *registration operations*.

Here's what I think is happening. You do see the 11k+ *registration operations* as shown on your graph:
[image]

Those are creates and updates to the same registration combined. So if you created a registration once and then ran an update on it 3 times, those will be counted as 4 *registration operations* over 1 *registration*. (It's a bit more complicated than that, but it's a simple way to think about it.)

And the green stripe shows a number of distinct registration IDs that you have  associated with the hub.

Comment: I see.Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to visually graph unique device registration (not registration operation)?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to plot the timeline of unique devices at the moment. One (inconvenient) way to workaround that would be to just keep track of the values by yourself.